# Logs not getting printed in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have some NSLog statements in my code and I am putting the app on someone's device and now I want to see the logs generated from my NSLog statements. When I attach the device with my machine and open the device logs from organizer of XCODE, I am not seeing the log statement printed by my code. However, if I install and run the application keeping the device attached with my machine logs gets printed on console.

What could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Console](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/console/id317676250?mt=8) application. It gives you all NSLog statements. I have faced this issue of not getting the device logs at times. Syncing the device usually solves the problem.